# Best way to bake rigid body physics?

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation, baking

I would like to save the locations and rotations (in the blend files itself or anywhere else) of the rigid body simulation, because I don't want to wait every time over and over again for blender to calculate whenever I press <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>. I know there are a few options:

- Bake to keyframes (in 'rigid body tools' bar at the left toolbar in 3d view/panel)
- Bake (in 'rigid body cache' section, 'scenes' tab in 'properties' panel)
- Bake all dynamics (same panel as 'Bake')

Which one is recommended? And what is exactly the difference between 'Bake' and 'Bake all dynamics'? Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Bake** (in the *rigid body cache* panel).

Storing the locations to keyframes on every frame is very inefficient and will make the size of your .blend skyrocket. The cache system used when baking is designed for exactly this purpose, and so is naturally more efficient.

*Bake all dynamics* will bake *all* physics simulations in the scene. This is useful for taking interactions between simulations into account without having to manually bake all the simulations in the right order. If you only have one simulation, then it's the same as *Bake*.

Comment: By 'all physics', does that include 'fluid', 'smoke' etc? :)

Comment: Smoke yes. Fluid is a little bit of a different animal than all the others.. I haven't tested it, but I suspect that it will *not* be baked by *bake all dynamics*. However this is the exception, not the rule..

Comment: When I press 'Bake', it will bake the rigid body physics of all objects in the scene, right? Even if they are not selected or visible?

Comment: @FacebFaceb It's not you ;) I took the liberty of editing it to add a few tags and tweaks here and there. If you don't like my edits you can always [roll them back](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/editing) :) Regarding your edited comment, yes. It will bake all rigid bodies in the scene regardless of visibility or selection.

Comment: Haha, thanks because I thought my question now looked way better than when I submitted it :P

Comment: Last question :) How I can I see which physics (rigid body, fluid, smoke, paint, soft body etc) are used in the complete scene/blendfile, without having to check for each mesh individually?

Comment: @FacebFaceb You might want to ask that in a new post. On this site we like to keep one post focused on one question. This helps keep info relevant to outsiders coming in from search engines etc. :)