# Rendering an animation in stages

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, animation

Can you render an animation in stages (I am not sure if that is the right word in english .. let's suppose we have an animation of 300 frames and I want to render the first 100 frames to PNG output at Day 1, the second 100 frames to PNG output at Day 2 and the third 100 frames to PNG output at Day 3) ?

Will this work ? Will I get the same animation when rendering the animation in one run ? And would this also be true when involving physics ? For instance fluid or fire/smoke simulation or particle systems ? Or force fields ?

At moment I use these settings for the smoke cache.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it will as long as you bake your physics first (I would recommend that it be to an external source - Make sure that you name your cache 1st). Then just be sure to set your render range in either the timeline OR the Render Panel >> Dimensions. Once your bake is done save your file and don't touch it except for rendering, and changing your range the next day.

**If you bake your Cache to Disk:**

1. It will save the folder in the same file location as your blend file.
2. You can copy both the blend file and the cache folder and start rendering on another machine for a different range if you have that at your disposal.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please have a look at the edit of my question. For smoke would I have to check External ? And what is the difference between Bake All Dynamics and Bake ?

Comment: You don't have to check External, it just makes more sense to not have the overhead of that in memory during render time. As far as the difference in baking [check this one out](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30537/best-way-to-bake-rigid-body-physics)

Comment: I saw another post that you made regarding the render times on this project (eg. 10 days), and for your sake, I'm hoping that you are able to shorten that as a side affect to this process.

Comment: if you have done the bake, should you free the bake ? Or is that one thing you should not do ?

Comment: So when I use a NAS, I could save the bake to the NAS and let different machine render pieces of the animation ?

Comment: Do not free the bake unless you feel that you need to recalculate (usually because you want to change the behavior). As for NAS ??? Not quite sure what you mean here, but I'm guessing Network Attached Storage? If this is what it is, then as long as your blend file exist in the same place as your cache folder and you haven't renamed anything then yes, that's the idea. The only problem for me is, I'm not sure what the file access will do to you. Meaning if one machine has it open, will the others fail on the same exact file. you may need to have a blend for each machine you plan to render on.

Comment: yes, NAS is Network Attached Storage. Both my blend files and blender data (incl bakes) are stored there. In this way I can work with the same blend file and blender data on both my MAC and Windows machine

Comment: One other note here. You may want to test the two machines on a single frame of the same animation. If one does a cpu and another does gpu, you might get some noticable difference (not certain about this, but it is worth testing).